# Script to import product thumbnails automatically magento 2 help

Tags: magento2, product-images

I tried to execute the following script

```
$_product->addImageToMediaGallery($returnUploadedImagePath, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false);
```

I am getting vendor error , is there a script to upload images to avoid the
error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The image does not exist. 
>   /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Gallery/Processor.php on line 131

Answer (score 0):

The method below looks for images in the folder “/pub/media/import/” and, if found, they get imported for the product.

```
protected function importImages(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $imageName = $product->getSku();
    $imageFolder = strtolower(explode('_', $imageName)[0]) . "/";

    $dir = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $mediaImportFolder = $dir->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

    if($this->isSetFlag('remove_existing_images')) {
        // remove images
        $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
        foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
            unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
        }
        $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
        $this->_productRepositoryInterface->save($product);
    }

    $product->setMediaGallery(array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));

    $i = $foundImages = 0;
    while($i < 10) {
        $i++;

        $imagePath = 'import/' . $imageFolder . $imageName . "_IMAGE" . $i . ".jpg";
        $imageAbsolutePath = $mediaImportFolder . '/' . $imagePath;

        if(!$imageAbsolutePath = $this->fileExists($imageAbsolutePath)) {
            continue 1;
        }

        $flags = ($foundImages == 0) ? ['image','thumbnail','small_image'] : [];

        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageAbsolutePath, $flags, false, false);

        $this->log(" - Image {$imagePath} imported with success for the product SKU {$product->getSku()}");
        $foundImages++;
    }

    if($foundImages == 0) {
        $this->log(" - No images found for the product SKU {$product->getSku()}");
    }

    return $this;
}
```